# Vimperator and Javascript: getting value of an object

Tags: javascript, vimperator

Let's say I've just open a random Stackoverflow page, then I open Console in Firefox and run something like this:

```
alert(document.getElementsByClassName("question-hyperlink")["0"]["firstChild"].textContent)
```

As a result, it will pop up me the question asked on that page (on this particular page it would be `Vimperator and Javascript: getting value of an object`).

Now, I want to use that value in a script with Vimperator. I add something like this to my `.vimperatorrc`

```
:js << EOF
function dummyFu() {
    var myElement = document.getElementsByClassName("question-hyperlink");
    alert(myElement["0"].firstChild.textContent);
}
EOF
map <F5> :js dummyFu()<CR>
```

However, when run, it says `TypeError: myElement[0] is undefined`.

So, what is wrong? Would be grateful for any suggestion, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/content

E.g., `content.document.getElementsByClassName("question-hyperlink")[0].firstChild.textContent;`

(No, it's not me, but [all the credits go](https://github.com/5digits/dactyl/issues/196) to [GitHub user dkearns](https://github.com/dkearns), actually. Thanks them a lot. :)